# Copy or Export Shared Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to copy or export a shared Google calendar that is listed under "Other Calendars."

I have found instructions on how to do this using the Public  Address in iCal format. However, for the calendar I wish to copy or export, I do not have this information. Under integrate, there are only a "calendar ID" and a "Public URL to this calendar."

When I open the Public URL in a new browser, I cannot find any option to Save As .ics, I can only find options to save it as a web archive.

How do I copy, save, or export it in a format that can be imported into Google calendar or even any calendar program?

Comment: Welcome. Please do remember as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a very easy workaround.

1. Install Thunderbird
2. Import your agendas (it will also process shared agendas)
3. Export your agenda in whatever format that suits you.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great answer when it comes to solving the issue. If somebody needs more details on how to achieve it, here is the official documentation from Mozilla Thunderbird. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-lightning-google-calendar You need to follow the instructions for the Read-Write access option.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to copy or export a shared Google calendar that is listed
>   under "Other Calendars.

The key word here is **shared**.
You **can not copy or export a shared Google calendar**. They are not yours, so you cannot do anything else but share them.

***Extra info:*** *Not even the default `Birthdays` calendar found can be exported or downloaded because it "Displays birthdays, anniversaries and other event dates of people **in Google Contacts.***"

[image: share calendars]